# Any examples of using material Autocomplete in material table rows in Angular 4

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material

I am trying to build a page with  material  table with  material Autocomplete coming in every row. I don't know any sample code that does that. Can you provide me any references on how to implement this?